# yet were treated to it

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the subject of "were treated to it"? "Were" is plural and I have no clue what is its subject.

> Trump's pardoned a bunch of the perpetrators and conspirators for keeping mum but that only goes to back up the fact that, indeed, something illegal actually occurred. It's hard to imagine such willful ignorance at work on a daily basis, **yet were treated to it** again and again. Pizzagate, Uranium One, Benghazi, crisis actors, hydr0xychloroquine, 'covid is the flu' — nothing is too inane to escape this guy's dutiful attention to suspect and contested accounts and his shamelessness in promoting them.

Comment: Could "were" actually be "we're" which is a contraction of "we are"?

Comment: it must be "we are treated to it"

Comment: Thank you.  Does "be treated to it" mean "be treated this way (be forced to accept such willful ignorance)"?  I especially don't understand "to it" - what does it exactly mean?

Comment: *to be treated to something* literally means to receive a treat. A treat is an enjoyable entity or phenomenon of some kind---you can receive a chocolate cake or a trip to the spa as a treat, for example. Here, it is being used ironically, to mean receiving or being subjected to something *unenjoyable*.

Comment: Thanks.   What does "it" refer to? Can it be expressed with "be treated with it" - that "to" has given me a hard time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Treated to [something]* is a phrase which means people are given something, or get to experience something. It implies someone is responsible for the thing happening, but it can be figurative too - e.g. you could be *treated to a beautiful sunset* without necessarily believing someone or something is doing it for you.

A *treat* is usually a good thing, something special and pleasant, that generally doesn't happen all the time - so it's a special event. And you can use the word ironically too, to describe bad things, like in this case.

So *it* just refers to the subject of the previous clause, the *wilful ignorance at work*. That's the treat you get to enjoy, every day!

*Treat with* means something else, it's generally used for treating an illness or condition, or adding something to a material to give it an improved property, so it's referring to the *treatment* you use. *Treat with* can also mean something along the lines of *negotiate with* (it's where *treaty* comes from) but that's less common to hear.

*Treat* as a verb alone isn't necessarily positive, by the way - you can *treat someone badly* and *treat* just refers to the way you act towards them.